# angular 2 inline style borderColor not working

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to change the border color , but it is not work.

There is my code:

```
<div [style.backgroundColor]="item.color"   [style.borderColor]="item.borderColor">
```

And in the css

```
display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
    border:2px solid ;//red;  
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
      border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
```

The backgroundColor work , but the border not.
I'm trying also :

```
[ngStyle]="{border: '2px solid(' + item.borderColor + ')'}"
```

But no effect.

Comment: It works well https://plnkr.co/edit/WKo9CfHF4eHc40ffNAaD?p=preview

Answer (score 13):

Try this simple solution for border to work :

```
[ngStyle]="{'border': '2px solid' + item.borderColor}"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this

```
[style.border]="'2px solid ' + item.borderColor"
```

Hope, It will help to you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some solution to make border-color dynamically changed -> In your ts file wrote this:

```
  get myStyles(): any {
    let color = 'red';
      return {
          'border':'1px',
          'border-style': 'solid',
          'border-color':this.dtService.border_color
      };
  }
```

Then in your html file -> ngStyle="myStyles"

This will make your border color change dynamically. I hope this will help you in some way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for the border, I fixed like this.

```html
<div [attr.style]="{'border 2px solid ' + item.borderColor | safeStyle"> </div>
```

Were `safeStyle` is

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'safeStyle' })
export class SafeStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value)
  }
}
```

*Found the solution on [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12009#issuecomment-482003167)*